# Amp form POST using PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, amp-html

I am posting a form using Amp and handling using PHP. I am getting following error:

> Form submission failed:: Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header

[image]

Code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST\['submitlogin'\]))
{
    $name = isset($_POST\['name'\]) ? $_POST\['name'\] : '' ;
    $output = \[
            'name' => $name
    \];
header("Content-type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("AMP-Same-Origin: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.ampproject.org");
header("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: *");
#header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");
echo json_encode($output);
die();

}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html amp>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js">
    </script>
    <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="canonical" href="localhost">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <title>AMP form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action-xhr="#" target="_top">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitlogin" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div submit-success>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        Success! Thanks for trying the
        <code>amp-form</code> demo! The name submited was {{name}}
    </template>
</div>
</body>enter code here
</html>
```

I have include all the headers, the only problem I am facing is that site is hosted on localhost using Apache. Kindly help me with what I need to do allow amp headers on localhost.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Sadly, we're not wizards who knows how your code looks like. You have to post your code, otherwise we can't help you. May also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for future questions.

Comment: Twinfriends : I was just editing the question , it got post on the way , now check the question with the code

Answer (score 2):

Try add the following lines to your .htaccess:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin "https://yourdomain.com"
```

Comment: Sorry just read you are working in localhost, not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

I found your question while searching for the same answer. While debugging the request I noticed the following query string added to the request

```
?__amp_source_origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080
```

and by adding

```
header('AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: '.'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

to the response, AMP stopped complaining.